# Enable sleep mode in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, power

How to get sleep mode in windows 8.1?

It doesn't have any option.

[image]

I checked power options too.

Comment: Your screenshot says Windows 8 and your question say Windows 8.1. Which is correct?

Comment: Its windows 8.1